# How to isolate cpu and ram for specific task. I already use "isolcpus" in the Grub setting to limit my CPU, but it does not get desired result

Tags: kernel, ram, python3, cpu, process

**The main issue is to calculate the execution time of my algorithm, which is run in Python, and get a fixed execution time for each execution of the algorithm on the same data.** I use the same data on every execution of the algorithm.

I am trying to calculate the execution time of my algorithm. When I run my algorithm, it provides different execution times for each run. I think this is due to my CPU and RAM random allocation to the algorithm. I want to isolate the limited CPU core and RAM for the testing execution time of my algorithm. **I already use "isolcpus" in the Grub setting to limit my CPU, but it does not help me.** The same issue has occurred.

**Is there any way to get a fixed execution time for my algorithm on each run for the same data?**

Answer (score 3):

It is generally hard to get a fixed execution time, but you can try the following to minimize the variance:

- OS-level things

  - Ensure that the GRUB setting actually appears in `cat /proc/cmdline`. If not, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot
  - Populate caches after every boot by running a trial run and discarding the results before doing the actual run. Basically just run your command twice and take your second run. This ensures all code and data is loaded into the page cache from memory, and `__pycache__` is generated when appropriate, so that the variable of disk access is eliminated
  - Ensure you actually set the CPU affinity for the specific process using `taskset -c <the core you used for isolcpus>`
  - Close unnecessary programs and use the TTY instead of the GUI. If this is not possible, at least use `sudo nice -20` so that the priority is set to max.
  - Your final command might look like `sudo taskset -c 1 nice -n -20 python ./my_algorithm.py`
- Programming-level things

  - Eliminate all print statements in your code. Many build systems were bottlenecked by the speed the terminal running them can handle their console output
  - Avoid randomized or nondeterministic algorithms. Many random number generators depend on the current system time, so call `setseed` or something. Certain sorting algorithms like Quicksort choose the pivot randomly, so use deterministic ones like Mergesort. These shouldn't have a massive impact, but you can set the system time if you insist.
  - Fixed execution times are near-impossible on a modern Intel/AMD CPU, possibly even with a PhD in cryptography. Some articles for inspiration would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack . However, you could consider installing Ubuntu on an older, single-core Raspberry Pi. That give a somewhat fixed execution time with the same techniques (Arduino would be completely fixed immediately)
- Hardware-level things:

  - Memory shouldn't matter. Just reboot and don't open extra programs. Your memory speed should be set to a constant speed by BIOS (though some BIOSes have bugs changing that on suspend, so don't do that). Advanced topics are memory cgroups and NUMA, but they shouldn't be necessary.
  - Set the CPU frequency to the lowest non-boost frequency for your CPU. This frees the CPU from needing to check whether the temperature or current are appropriate enough to run at high frequencies. Since indicator-cpufreq might not work these days, you should use sudo and bash to echo one number into `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_{max_freq,min_freq,setspeed}`. Set the governor to either `powersave` or `performance` so that it is more likely to stick to that one number
  - Disable hyper-threading in BIOS, otherwise you need to adapt your taskset and isolcpus to it
  - If on a laptop, make sure it is not overheating and thermal throttling

But why do you want your algorithm to complete in an fixed amount of time? You probably want a single number to report for your (algorithm, data) pair. In that case, it is customary to sample across many runs. Tools like https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/utils/hyperfine will determine the number of runs necessary, and output a stable number. Failing that, it will give you the standard deviation. Additionally, if your algorithm runs in much less than a few seconds, you should wrap it in a `for` loop on the Python side.

Comment: Thank you for your information @Daniel T.

I need a fixed time for my report on the university where I analyze the performance of my algorithm.